# Verify & Publish Source Code

Tags: solidity, verify

I tried to Verify & Publish Contract Source Code for my token

and the error happened like this Compiler debug log:
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (Compiler Exception)
For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

you can take a look at the attached image

[image]

what is wrong with it? why did this error happen?
how I can correct it?

regards

Comment: You have a syntax error in your contract. `contract NTC token is Ownable` is not valid solidity.

Comment: in this case, should I change the NTC token to another symbol?

Comment: It's not valid Solidity, it won't compile. I suggest you learn more about Solidity and its syntax.

Comment: I wish if you have a specific website for solidity, coz I do not know which is correct, I am new.

Comment: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/